# Trigger GWT class' method from inside other class

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT page that contains a lot of different fields, which the user needs to fill out. When the user is done filling out the form, they can click on a button on this page, which opens up a PopupPanel with a summary of what they have input. If the user decides all the data they've entered is correct, they have the option of clicking on an "OK" button on this PopupPanel. What I would like to achieve is that when the user clicks on OK, the PopupPanel closes and a method in the initial class (and using the initial class' variables) is triggered. I am unable to use EventBus because of certain restraints.

In my initial class I have this click handler:

```
buttonAnle.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {

            if ( validateTimespan(subs) && validateSubumfeldTimespan(subs) )
            {
                summary();
            }

        }
    });
```

The method summary() shows the popuppanel:

```
    private void summary()
{
    int subumfelderNr = subs.getRowCount();
    int werbeformenNr = kats.getRowCount();
    int days = (int) (datumBis.getValue().getTime() - datumVon.getValue().getTime()) / 86400000;
    new SubprogramPopup(umfeldText.getTextBoxText(), subumfelderNr - 1, werbeformenNr - 1, days + 1).show();

}
```

The popup appears, now I need a way for the OK button's click to trigger a method in my initial class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity.
Why can't you use GWTEventBus ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, I'm a new employee and I was only told that EventBus isn't an option, so now I'm looking into alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be using a interface inside the SubprogramPopup. Add this code to the SubprogramPopup class:

```
interface MyHandler {
    void doSomething();
}
```

and add MyHandler as another parameter to the constructor of the SubprogramPopup.

```
SubprogramPopup(Textbox textbox,
                int value01,
                int value02,
                int value03,
                MyHandler handler) {}
```

Now, if you are creating the SubprogramPopup you can use the handler to add something, that should be executed if needed.

```
new SubprogramPopup(umfeldText.getTextBoxText(),
                    subumfelderNr - 1,
                    werbeformenNr - 1,
                    days + 1,
                    new MyHandler() {
                      public void doSomething() {
                        // enter your code here ... 
                      }
                    }).show();
```